# Apple Push Notification Services provider connect for 3rd party app

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I've read the Apple docs on APNs and there's one thing I'm not sure about. First, some background on where this is coming from.

In the company I work at, we develop an SDK that interfaces with our webservices. One part of the SDK is sending messages and we're thinking about push notifications when the user is not online (app suspended/not running). We don't have an app ourselves, but would like to provide this feature to users of the SDK and our platform.

So: Can we create an authentication token or certificate of our own to connect to APNs and then push a notification to an app developed by a 3rd party (with their app token)? Or do we need to collect all the information from the 3rd party and basically impersonate them?

Google and Microsoft provide a service like that, but I'm not sure what's happening behind the scenes.

Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, You will need to collect all the information from developer who is using your SDK.

-  APN Certificates p12 files
- Password
- Device Token - Allow some method to pass device token from your SDK.

In other words, you need to do something like GCM do for iOS.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: I had very slim hopes that that was not the case. Thanks.